# How to debug Live Server and Live AppleID in IAP?

Tags: ios, debugging, in-app-purchase, real-time

I am working with Live url of the IAP server, but still I'm getting Sandbox Environment. How can I debug with Live server and Real appleId rather than sandbox environment.

I have posted This url:- https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Comment: I don't believe you can use the live store unless your app has been downloaded from the app store

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this. However, data for IAP in sandbox and live always be same.

Comment: Yes, Sandeep but the problem is we are unable to get products, In live app.

And it is working fine with Sandbox Server.

Answer (score -1):

I am no sure, but I think it can help you.
[InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)